# Huion 680s drivers Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, drivers, graphics-tablet

I recently bought a Huion 680s drawing tablet and I'm searching for some drivers.
I've already looked through Huion's driver page, to no avail. I have also looked through the DIGImend GitHub page and it seems it doesn't support my tablet. Thanks in advance!

Extra Details: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you solved this issue, yet? I'm considering switching over to Linux and use the same drawing pad. Would love to know the workaround before I make the shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
git clone https://github.com/joseluis/huion-linux-drivers.git
```

That's it, it started working for me.

Comment: Please detail the steps you followed to solve the problem.